Detect all isogenies of an elliptic curve over a given number field

Given $K$ a number field and $E/K$ an elliptic curve, is there an algorithm which gives all the elliptic curves $F/K$ isogenous to $E$ (up to isomorphism)?

Or is there a bound on how many $F/K$ are isogenous to $E/K$?

If $E/K$ and $F/K$ are isogenous is the isogeny necessarily defined over $K$?


For a fixed degree, I know we can use modular polynomials to find $F/K$. However is there a bound on the degree? I know that when $K=\mathbb{Q}$, this follows from Mazur's theorem.

My answer to this question contains links to algorithms even over number fields. That should help for (1).

(3) No, because of quadratic twists this isn't true even for isomorphic curves (degree 1 isogenies).

Thank you. I have a follow-up naive question. In this algorithm, they show how to find primes $l$ such that $E/K$ has an $l$-isogeny. It seems to me that in this context the $l$-isogenies are thought to be defined over $K$, is that right?

The algorithms look for all isogenies $\phi$ leaving $E$ defined over a fixed number field $K$, which is equivalent to finding their kernels $C = E[\phi]$ as subgroup of $E$ defined over $K$. The codomain $E/C$ is defined over $K$.

If $\phi: E \to E'$ is an isogeny defined over $F$ between two curves defined over $K$, then $\phi$ is the composition of an isogeny of that degree defined over $K$ and an isomorphism from $E/E[\phi]$ to $E'$ defined over $F$.

@ChrisWuthrich thank you! The last comment clarifies my confusion.
